# Create new column from unique ID to variable names in R

Tags: r

I want to create a new variable. The data I have in column one is: 'ID 1', 'ID 2', 'ID 3' and 'ID 4'. I want each ID in column one to be assigned different cities 'City 1', 'City 2', 'City 3' and 'City 4'. I hereby need to assign each ID to the cities and create a new column.

| column_one | City |
| --- | --- |
| ID 1 | City 1 |
| ID 2 | City 2 |
| ID 3 | City 3 |
| ID 4 | City 4 |

How can I best do this? I tried this code:

`df2$City <- ifelse(df2$column_one %in% c('ID 1','ID 2', 'ID 3','ID 4'),'City 1','City 2', 'City 3', 'City 4')`

But I get an error. How can I solve this task?

Comment: So do you need 16 rows in this case?

Comment: @AnilGoyal I have data from 2017 to 2020, but only 4 ID numbers that are the ID numbers for 4 different cities. I want to assign the city name in a separate column to these IDs for the entire dataset.

Answer (score 0):

If you dataframe is:

```
df2 <- data.frame(column_one=paste("ID",seq(4)))
```

Then you can simply add City by gsub-ing the ID column

```
df2$City <- paste("City",gsub("ID ","", df2$column_one))
```

EDIT: this would be even shorter:

```
df2$City <- gsub("ID","City", df2$column_one)
```

EDIT2: if you want to replace manually

```
 library(mgsub)
 df2$City <- mgsub(df2$column_one, 
              c("ID 1","ID 2", "ID 3", "ID 4"), 
              c("City 1","City 2","City 3","City 4"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the example code. However, when I do this: ```df2 <-data.frame(column_one=paste("ID",seq(4)))
df2$City <- paste("City1", "City2", "City3", "City4",gsub("ID1 ","ID2", "","ID3", "ID4", df2$column_one))```all the city names are displayed for each ID (that are named 1,2,3,4 and not the unique values I have for each city.

Comment: there is no need to specify the number.  You just replace ID with City and the number will stay the same. However, if you want to do it the way you did, you just have to change your code to `paste(c("City1", "City2", "City3", "City4"),gsub("ID .", "", df2$column_one))`

Comment: Thank you! I tried your edited code: ```df2$City <- gsub("ID","City", df2$column_one)```and it works when I put one city into the code. However, I get an error when taking all four cities and IDs into the code like this: ```df2$City <- gsub("ID1","ID2","ID3","ID4", "City1", "City2", "City3", "City4", df2$column_one)```. Any suggestions on how to make the code applicable for all four ID and cities? Right now it only shows ID1 with city 1

Comment: Unfortunately, gsub does not take its input like that. Why do you want to list every single city though? If your goal is to replace the word ID with the word City, than you can really just use the code as in my EDIT code. If you really need to list every ID and every city, you can use mgsub (see my 2nd EDIT above)

Comment: Thank you! This works :) I need to see the city name and the ID for the city, for each row, not just the column name.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `left_join`.  Will this work?

```
df1 <- data.frame(column_one = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4"),
                  city = c("City1", "City2", "City3", "City4"))

> df1
  column_one  city
1        ID1 City1
2        ID2 City2
3        ID3 City3
4        ID4 City4
column_one = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4")
df2 <- data.frame(ID = sample(column_one, 10, T),
                  dummy = sample(1:100, 10))
    ID dummy
1  ID3    50
2  ID4    99
3  ID4    35
4  ID1    86
5  ID3    56
6  ID1    31
7  ID2    15
8  ID1     9
9  ID3    74
10 ID3    17
```

Then do this

```
df2 %>% left_join(df1, by = c("ID" = "column_one"))
    ID dummy  city
1  ID3    50 City3
2  ID4    99 City4
3  ID4    35 City4
4  ID1    86 City1
5  ID3    56 City3
6  ID1    31 City1
7  ID2    15 City2
8  ID1     9 City1
9  ID3    74 City3
10 ID3    17 City3
```

Comment: Thank you! So the last code: ```df2 %>% left_join(df1, by = c("ID" = "column_one"))``` I am supposed to use the last dataset version before df2, and I get an error: Join columns must be present in data. x Problem with `ID`. Am I supposed to write in all four different ID numbers here: by = c("ID" = "column_one"))?

Comment: No! What are the column names in two dataframes? If you haven't a look up dataframe, then create one

Answer (score 0):

You already have the **gsub** option mentioned earlier by @Solarion. The following are 2 more alternatives.

1. dplyr option equal to gsub
   df2%>%
   mutate(city = str_replace(column_one,"ID","City"))
2. In an event that text "ID" is not uniform in column_one
   df2%>%
   tidyr::separate(column_one,sep=" ",into=c(NA,"id"),remove=FALSE)%>% # separate on the space and ignore the first part of the text , in this case ID.
   mutate(city = paste("City",id),.keep="unused")